# Does a transaction with no net effect touch the database on-disk?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a circumstance where I need to update some table rows, marking the ones that do not appear in an external data-source as disabled (i.e. update `active=0`).  The straight-forwards solution is to `BEGIN` a transaction, `UPDATE` every row to `active=0`, and then scan the remote data, doing an `UPDATE` for each entry that should be `active=1` to put it back.  I have around 1k rows, so this should be a relatively quick operation, even if there is a lot of inefficient query parsing.

However, this data will often not change at all.  Hence, in the majority of cases, the net effects of the transaction will be zero change.  If the database engine will resolve the whole thing, detect that nothing is changing, and not change anything as a result, that would be ideal.  However, if it is going to go through and actually update every row, every time, I would rather find another solution.

Comment: the point of BEGIN is starting a transaction, MySQL does not change the table/index files after you COMMIT.. meaning all update/inserts in the transaction are flushed at once to the disk..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, how do you think InnoDB handles an uncommitted transaction if it modifies more pages than fit in the buffer pool?

Comment: *"how do you think InnoDB handles an uncommitted transaction if it modifies more pages than fit in the buffer pool?"* WAL (Write Ahead Log) which is yes a disk file... Yes @BillKarwin mine comment was to much simplified....

Comment: And if WAL writes wrap around to the start of the log file, it _must_ start flushing modified pages to disk, into the tablespace, even if those modified pages are still uncommitted.

Comment: Depending on what you are using to scan the remote data and prepare the updates perhaps it would be easier to keep track of the updates and once you have all of them start your transaction, do all of the updates and commit it. If there aren't any updates don't do anything.

Comment: @Dave: In this case, it's querying stuff from remote systems.  I could query the DB to get a list of existing things, then mark my list as a I scan the remotes, and then only touch the unmarked entries -- but it's significantly easier to just script "remote-data --> SQL query" without any local data storage.  Your suggestion is basically exactly my "Plan B" for if the answer here was that it's abusive on the DB and I shouldn't.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: To clarify, my question is that if the total net result of the transaction is nothing, if it still flushes anything to disk.  For example, if we start with a=0, `BEGIN; UPDATE a=1; UPDATE a=0; COMMIT` has no net effect.  So the question is basically if mariadb is smart enough to recognize that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo. I created a table with just a simple integer in a row.

```
mysql> create table t ( i int );
mysql> insert into t set i = 42;
```

I check the current number of log writes.

```
mysql> show status like 'innodb_log_write_requests';
+---------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name             | Value   |
+---------------------------+---------+
| Innodb_log_write_requests | 5432152 |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

Then change the value in the row with an UPDATE and confirm it resulted in a log write:

```
mysql> update t set i = 43;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> show status like 'innodb_log_write_requests';
+---------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name             | Value   |
+---------------------------+---------+
| Innodb_log_write_requests | 5432153 |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

Next, make an UPDATE that has no net effect.

```
mysql> update t set i = 43;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Notice `Changed: 0`.

Look at the log writes, it is also unchanged:

```
mysql> show status like 'innodb_log_write_requests';
+---------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name             | Value   |
+---------------------------+---------+
| Innodb_log_write_requests | 5432153 |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Clever to look at the log write requests to determine if I've been hitting disk.  I just further confirmed that a pair of `UPDATES` that cancel out within a transaction do not change that write requests variable.

Comment: InnoDB is a complex engine @JamesK as innoDB also can do [Read-Ahead](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-disk-io.html) which also might do "unexpected" disk I/O in those cases.. I would say configure those redo logs on a (possible separated) SSD to keep performance very high..

Comment: @RaymondNijland have you ever moved redo logs to a separate storage device and had it make a big difference? I have not found that to be the case. If the performance is bottlenecked on redo writes, moving it to another device will only give a slight improvement, because at that point, it's likely that the writes will just keep increasing until they saturate the separate storage device.

Comment: Well in cases when the buffer pool was cold and all/most queries also needed to acces disk, i did in fact notice (small) differences separating redo log to a other disk .. In RDMS disk IOPS is offcource the critical point where performance can be lost also matters offcource how many transactions at the same time/qeuries are running..Why would you want to waste disk IOPS for logging annyhow i think its a opinion issue.. But a cold buffer pool nowadays is not a thing annymore as you can dump and reload the buffer pool in the more modern MySQL versions when a restart would be needed..

Comment: .. offcource as hardware factors in the differences are less or even not noticable when you run on completly on SSD/SSHD(hybrid) and not using HDD 7200/10000/15000 rpm for that matter forgot to mention..

Answer (score 1):

I think it has pretty much been concluded that there is disk I/O for your no-op.  Let's discuss the task at hand:

Instead of actually modifying the database, can you keep in memory a list of the items that *might* be disabled?  After you have made the scan, if there are any to disable, then proceed to disable all in a single `UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (...)`

On another topic...  If you are actually doing this

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE a=0;  -- for all rows
COMMIT;
-- all are disabled briefly
BEGIN;
UPDATE a=1 WHERE id = ...  -- one row at a time
COMMIT;
```

Then you have a window where everthing is disabled.  You probably don't want that.